# A few questions on the paper named "On a Sobolev inequality with remainder terms"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I was reading a paper of Lu-Wei named "On a Sobolev inequality with remainder terms" ([link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/proc/2000-128-01/S0002-9939-99-05497-0/S0002-9939-99-05497-0.pdf)).

and I have quite a few questions regarding that.

(1) In page 78 they got a system of two equations involving $\phi$ and $w_i$ and the claim is $\phi_i=0$ when $\mu\leq p$ and $i>N+2$. Then it's written WLOG assume that $\phi_i<0$ on $(0,r_1)$ and $\phi_i(r_1)=0$ ( why it has to be the case, can't it be negative everywhere, why it has to hit $0$?)
Also in the very next line it's written that as $i>N+2$ ,$\phi_i(0)=w_i(0)=\phi_i'(0)=w_i'(0)=0$.I couldn't see how this follows ?

Any help is very much helpful for my better understanding of the material.

Comment: It would be easier for the readers if you can either provide the full citation information of the paper you are looking at, or, better yet, include a DOI link to the electronic version (or to an arXiv preprint).

Comment: Sure I am adding it.